# cannot access a data table located in another server from a stored procedure in one server of SQL server 2008 R2 management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, windows-7

I need to access a data table located in another server (target_server) from a stored procedure in one server (server1) of SQL server 2008 R2 management studio.

I have added the target server:

```
EXEC sp_addserver 'target_server' , 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE
EXEC sp_serveroption 'target_server' , 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE
```

But, when I run the stored procedure to access the target server, I got this error:

```
Login failed for user 'my_login_user_name'.
```

The target server's password is different from the login password of my server1. But, I have successfully logged into it and added it to the management studio with correct password.

Why can't I access the target server from the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_addserver is a bit old (in 2008, I beleive it's only included to be backwards compatabile with sql server 2000).  Unless I'm way off...use a combination of SP_addlinkedserver (similiar usage as sp_addserver) to set up the connection. (edit to add...your original sp_addserver should already work, no point redoing this step unless you really want to)

Then use SP_addlinkedsrvlogin to define the user access:

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin [ @rmtsrvname = ] 'rmtsrvname' 
 [ , [ @useself = ] 'TRUE' | 'FALSE' | NULL ] 
 [ , [ @locallogin = ] 'locallogin' ] 
 [ , [ @rmtuser = ] 'rmtuser' ] 
 [ , [ @rmtpassword = ] 'rmtpassword' ]
```

Comment: If you prefer graphics over the text line...SSMS allows you to enter the lines in a wizard like setup.  Under your server you will see server Objects >> linked Servers.  Security tab will allow you to define a seperate login/pass

Comment: That is defined by the user account you are using to log into the remote server.  IE. If you want read only access to that linked server, then create a readonly account on the linked server.

Comment: Not sure if you can...you'll need to find someone with sysadmin that can create / alter user accounts.